# Java method for implementing bank transfer from savings account into checking account

Tags: java, class, methods

I have the following method into Account Class

```
public void Transfer(int accountNo, double amount)
{
    this.accountNo = accountNo;
    double savingBal= this.getSavingBal();
    if (this.savingBal > amount)
    {this.savingBal=-amount;
    this.checkingBal=+amount;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Insufficent fonds into savings account");
    }

}
```

And this code into Main Class:

//

```
 Account b = new Account();
```

//

```
  System.out.println("Please mention the amout you whish to transfer and the account");
            amount = s.nextDouble();
            accountNo = s.nextInt();
            b.Transfer(accountNo, amount);
```

But the result printed into the console is always:
"Insufficent funds"

Please help,

Sincerly,

Full Account class

```
package atmsimulation;
import java.util.*;

public class Account {
private int accountNo;
private double checkingBal;
private double savingBal;

//Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Account ()
        {
        this.checkingBal=0;    
        this.savingBal=0;
        this.accountNo=0;
        }

  public Account(int accountNo, double checkingBal, double savingBal) {
        this.accountNo = accountNo;
        this.checkingBal = checkingBal;
        this.savingBal = savingBal;
    }
//makes a @Payment
public void Payment(double amount)
{
    this.checkingBal=-amount;
}
//makes a @Deposit
public void Deposit(double amount)
{
    this.checkingBal=+amount;
}
//makeks a transfer from @savings into @checking account
public void Transfer(int accountNo, double amount)
{
    this.accountNo = accountNo;
    double savingBal= this.getSavingBal();
    if (this.savingBal > amount)
    {this.savingBal=-amount;
    this.checkingBal=+amount;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Insufficent fonds into savings account");
    }

}

    public void setCheckingBal(double checkingBal) {
        this.checkingBal = checkingBal;
    }

    public void setSavingBal(double savingBal) {
        this.savingBal = savingBal;
    }

    public int getAccountNo() {
        return accountNo;
    }

    public void setAccountNo(int accountNo) {
        this.accountNo = accountNo;
    }

      public double getSavingBal() {
        return this.savingBal;
    }

    public double getCheckingBal() {
        return this.checkingBal;
    }



}
```

Comment: whats is getSavingBal?

Comment: where is the getSavingBal() code?

Comment: according to your code the printed message should be `"Insufficent fonds into savings account"`.

Comment: savingBal? not sure what that's supposed to mean, but you do know that the postfix notation you are using is actually setting it to the -(amount) and not (savingBal - amount)?

Comment: getSvaingBal is a getter which returns the Saving account balance.  public double getSavingBal() {
        return this.savingBal;
    }

Comment: `new Account()` leads to an object with 0 as a `savingBal` assuming that `s` is a `Random` that will give an amount > 0 your if will always fail.

Comment: First I created into main class an array of object and permit the user to add the Account Number, initial Savings Balance and then Checkig Balance.
            a[i]= new Account(accountNo,savingsBal,checkingBal);
Pls help me with a method to check if is the object I have created, the account number on which we want apply the reatrive operation. If the account number is found then it s savings balance that can be used by the transfer method.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.savingBal=-amount;
```

is a typo it should be

```
this.savingBal-=amount;
```

Similar typo on the very next line. These are probably causing your problem; if they are not and there is another problem, they would cause the very same problem if you fixed the other problem.